# How to modify dynamically the roles of the logged user in Spring Security 4?

Tags: java, spring-security

i'm trying to update the roles associated with the current logged user without log out, but it's not working as i wish.

Here is my code  :

```
PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authtoken_orig = (PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder
        .getContext().getAuthentication();

Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> Authorities_orig = authtoken_orig.getAuthorities();
ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority> Authorities_new = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();

for (GrantedAuthority sga : Authorities_orig) {
    SimpleGrantedAuthority tmpsga = (SimpleGrantedAuthority) sga;
    if (tmpsga.getAuthority().compareTo("ROLE_UNKNOWN") != 0
            && tmpsga.getAuthority().compareTo("ROLE_SIGNER") != 0) {
        Authorities_new.add(tmpsga);
    }
}

SimpleGrantedAuthority role_signer_auth = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_SIGNER");
Authorities_new.add(role_signer_auth);

PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authtoken_new = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
        authtoken_orig.getPrincipal(), authtoken_orig.getCredentials(), Authorities_new);
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext().setAuthentication(authtoken_new);
```

Please could you advice ?

Thanks in advance

David L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First eval Granted Authority for the logged-in user like:

```
GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = getNextRoleToAssign(context.getUserDetails());
```

Now, then initialiaze UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken by using below code:

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authorisedUser, passowrd,Collections<GrantedAuthorities>);
```

Finally, set this Authentication into the Security context for the current User as mentioned below:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Comment: In my case, i work with a client certification authentication... therefore, the securitycontextholder contains a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken  instead of a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken... Is the problem related to this method ? Because, i tried your method before trying to clear the context as i do in this sample

Answer (score 0):

Your method works, my roles assumption was erroneously based on the principal authorities and not on the authentication authorities. The result of

```
sc.getAuthentication().getAuthorities()
```

is not the same as

```
((UserDetails)sc.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getAuthorities()
```

(Where `sc` is the `securitycontext`)